# How to email specific staff the daily tasks allocated to them

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code that sends an email to all staff.

I want to include the tasks assigned to the Staff in the email.

"A1" will have the staff name. "B1-B5" will have the tasks". There is a blank row followed by the next "staff" member.
"A7" would have the next staff name.

As the number of tasks allocated to each staff member is random, the above is just an example of how the spreadsheet works.

I have a sheet with the staff names and a list of the email addresses next to them.

I copied the below and it is working.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20181102
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xName As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    With xMailItem
        .To = "sales@stevesoultltd.co.uk"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "TEST"
        .Body = "Hi," & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "File is now updated."
        .Attachments.Add xName
        .Display
       '.send
    End With
    Set xMailItem = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You should loop trhough your sheet, checking how many tasks does every manager in A1 have. Then copy the cells and add them as a range. Every manager would trigger the mail macro but you need to variabilize stuff like the `.To` and the attachments/body. It's not hard, but it is indeed tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you put the staff member's email address in the sheet, for example in `C1` opposite the manager's name? (or even instead of the manager's name)

If it's in C1, your code should look like this.

```vba
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Dim xOutApp As Object, xMailItem As Object
    Dim xName As String, lManager as Long, lTask as Long, shtTasks as Worksheet
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set shtTasks = ActiveSheet
    xName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

   'Loop through Managers
    lManager = 1
    Do Until lManager >= shtTasks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If shtTasks.Range("A" & lManager) <> "" Then 'to prevent blank emails being created on lines with no manager
        Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With xMailItem
            .To = shtTasks.Range("C" & lManager) 'This is the cell with the email address in it
            .Subject = "TEST"
            .Body = "Hi," & chr(13) & chr(13) & "File is now updated." & chr(13) & "Your tasks are: "

            'Loop through Tasks:
            lTask = lManager
            Do Until shtTasks.Range("B" & lTask) = ""
                .Body = .Body & " " & shtTasks.Range("B" & lTask) & ", "
                lTask = lTask + 1
            Loop
            .Body = Left(.Body, Len(.Body)-2) & "." 'replace the last comma with a full stop

            .Attachments.Add xName
            .Display
            '.Send
            Set xMailItem = Nothing
            lManager = lTask + 1 'Move to next manager
        End With
        End If
    Loop
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you mate, this is exactly what i needed it to do. is there a way i can have it send without the email pop up?

Comment: Yes sure! The line with the `send` command is currently commented out (the apostrophe `'` before that line makes it a comment not an action) - this is common for debugging. Just change `'.Send` to `.Send` and you're away (I suggest you remove or comment-out the `.Display` line above it, you won't need to display the email if you're sending it straight away)

Comment: If this solution worked for you please accept it as an answer to the question (green tick mark next to the answer)